# Stored Class instance objects in dictionary. How do I get them out?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

Context: I'm in a Programming Concepts course. the assignment is to define a Person class, a Customer subclass.

*Write a class named  Person with data attributes for a person’s name, address, and telephone number. Next, write a class named  Customer that is a subclass of the  Person class. The  Customer class should have a data attribute for a customer number and a Boolean data attribute indicating whether the customer wishes to be on a mailing list. Demonstrate an instance of the  Customer class in a simple program.*

I have been able to:

- Create class and subclass
- Get user input to define customer name, number, address, phone and yes/no for mailer
- Create instance of the Customer class object as CurrentCustomer
- Store that class object as a value in a Customers dictionary, using CustomerNumber as the key.

Where I am having trouble:

- Getting the object instance back from the dictionary, and using it to display the customers' data one by one. basically for key in Customers, print the values for Customer class object CurrentCustomer
  *example: a header that reads:

  Customer Number -- Name -- Address -- Phone -- Mailing List?*

  *then:

  Customer 1 -- John Smith - 123 Easy Street Smalltown, ST -- (555) 123 -1234 -- True*

**The way the instructor has outlined setting up the classes is as follows:**

**Define the Person class.**

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,address,phone):
        self.__name = name
        self.__address = address
        self.__phone = phone

**Write mutators for the attributes.**
def set_name(self,name):
    self.__name = name
def set_address(self, address):
    self.__address = address
def set_phone(self, phone):
    self.__phone = phone

# Write accessors for the attributes.
def get_name(self):
    return self.__name
def get_address(self):
    return self.__address
def get_phone(self):
    return self.__phone
```

**Define the Customers subclass.**

```
class Customer(Person):

    # Initialize the Customer class object
    def __init__(self, name, address, phone, customer_number, mailing_list):

        # Call Person class init method.
        Person.__init__(self, name, address, phone)

        # Initialize Customer class specific attributes.
        self.__customer_number = customer_number
        self.__mailing_list = mailing_list

    # Write mutators for Customer class attributes
    def set_customer_number(self, customer_number):
        self.__customer_number = customer_number
    def set_mailing_list(self, mailing_list):
        self.__mailing_list = mailing_list

    # Write Accessors for Customer class attributes.
    def get_customer_number(self):
        return self.__customer_number
    def get_mailing_list(self):
        return self.__mailing_list
```

**Here is how I have the main function set up currently to get customer information and store the object in thedictionary:**

**Define main function.**

```
def main():

# Initialize empty list to store customer numbers.
CustomerNumbers = []

# initialize empty dictionary to store Customer class instances.
Customers = {}

# Greet user.
print("Hello. Let's enter our customer records.\n")

# Get number of customers.
NumCustomers = get_num_customers()
if NumCustomers > 1:
    print("\nGot it! We will be entering " + str(NumCustomers) +" customers.")
else:
    print("\nGot it! We are entering " + str(NumCustomers) +" customer.")

# Fill list of customer numbers
for Count in range (1, NumCustomers+1):
    CustomerNumbers.append('Customer Number ' + str(Count))

# Store each customer's data into a dictionary with Customer Number as the Key
for i in CustomerNumbers:
    CustomerNumber = i
    CurrentCustomer = CustomerNumber
    Name, Address, Phone, Mailing_List = get_customer_info(CurrentCustomer)
    CustomerData = Customer(Name, Address, Phone, CustomerNumber, Mailing_List)
    Customers[CurrentCustomer] = CustomerData
    print(Name +"'s information saved.")


print("\n\t\t Customer Data ")
print("\t\t===============")
print("\nCustomer Name\t\tCustomer Number\t\tAddress\t\tPhone Number\tMailing List?\n")
```

**Currently using, but have tried several different ways to get the Class object back:**
for key, in Customers:
print(Customer.get_name())

**Output**

```
         Customer Data 
        ===============

Customer Name       Customer Number     Address     Phone Number    Mailing List?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/My Drive/Personal/Fall 2021/COP 2510 - Concepts of Programming/Chapter 11/Clark_J_Chapter_11_Assignment_3.py", line 243, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:/My Drive/Personal/Fall 2021/COP 2510 - Concepts of Programming/Chapter 11/Clark_J_Chapter_11_Assignment_3.py", line 109, in main
    for key, in Customers:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

Comment: Get rid of the `,` after `for key`

Comment: Why don't you use `key` in your `for` loop?

Comment: `for customer in Customers.values(): print(customer)`

Comment: `for key, customer in Customers.items(): print(key, customer)`

Comment: @Barmar,

Thank you, I'm still pretty new to this, so forgive my ignorance here. Are the two suggestions for code two separate ways to get the same result or do I need to use them in conjunction with one another?

I replaced `    for key, in Customers:
        print(Customer.get_name())` **with** `for customer in Customers.values(): print(customer)`

and got the output:
`<__main__.Customer object at 0x000001DAECE3D490>`

Comment: The first just prints the customers, the second prints the dictionary keys along with their corresponding customers.

Comment: @Barmar - Thank you!

That second one worked with a little modification. I just added the Class accessor method to the end of customer:
`print (customer.get_name())` 
and  it worked! Thank you!